# How to loop if statements in C

Tags: c++, c

So i have this if statement

```
if (c[1] < c[0] && c[2] < c[1] && c[3] < c[2] ...)
```

I dont know exactly how many statements it will be, it can be from 1 to 8:

```
if (c[1] < c[0])

if (c[1] < c[0] && c[2] < c[1] && c[3] < c[2] ... c[8] < c [7])
```

And i need to automate this code, but I have no idea how

Here is what i tried to do:

```
int i = 0;
int n; // number of statements
while(i < n)
{
   if(c[i+1] < c[0])
      if(c[i+2] < c[i+1])
                ...
   i++;              
}
```

Ps. I can only use while loop

Comment: Can you recurse (loop in disguise)?

Comment: C or C++? Please take the time to study the tags you apply. Also, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I didn't notice "_Ps. I can only use while loop_" before. Why exclude using a `for` loop in C or using a standard algorithm in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a counter and increment it every true condition end of while you can check it is equals to the number of statements or not

```
    int i = 0;
    int n; // number of statements
    int counter = 0;
    while(i < n)
    {
       if(c[i+1] < c[i])
           counter++;
                    ...
       i++;              
    }
    if(counter == n) // this will be your true condition
    else // then it false
```

Answer (score 2):

If your conditions are always written in a [Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), then the logic remains the same if you add conditions incrementally:

### CNF (`a && b && c && ...`)

```c
int result = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    result &= (c[i + 1] < c[i]);
}
if (result) {
    printf("True\n");
else {
    printf("False\n");
}
```

### DNF (`a || b || c || ...`)

(this one does not solve the problem in the post, it's just for the sake of an example)

```c
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    result |= (c[i + 1] < c[i]);
}
if (result) {
    printf("True\n");
else {
    printf("False\n");
}
```

You can also squeeze some extra efficiency by terminating the loops whenever `false` is found in CNF, or `true` is found in DNF (see [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

Comment: @TedLyngmo I put the DNF variant there as a complementary example and I'm aware it doesn't answer  OP's question, but you make a good point that I did not make that clear enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

/* ... */

    bool sorted = true;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]); ++i) {
        if(!(c[i] < c[i-1])) {
            sorted = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(sorted) {
        /* ... */
    }
```

C++:

```
#include <algorithm>   // std::is_sorted
#include <iterator>    // std::begin, std::end
#include <type_traits> // std::remove_extent

//...

    if(std::is_sorted(std::begin(c), std::end(c),
                      std::greater<std::remove_extent<decltype(c)>::type>{})) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your condition in the loop while like this

```
int i=0;
while(i<(n-1)&&c[i]>c[i+1])
{
   i++;
}
if(i==(n-1))
{
     printf("\nTrue condition \n");
}
else
{
     printf("\nFalse condition \n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy if not necessarily the most verbose way:

```
int i = 0;
while( ++i < n && c[i] < c[i-1] )
  ; // empty loop body

if ( i == n )
  // all tests passed
else
  // c[i] >= c[i-1]
```

The result of `++i` is the current value of `i` plus 1, and as a side effect `i` is incremented.  So this loops from `i = 1..n-1`.